# Existence of neutral element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

I have a question in the following exercise:

> Let $*$ be the binary operation defined on $\Bbb R$ by: $$x*y=xy+(x^2-1)(y^2-1)$$
> $\forall x,y\in \Bbb R$.
>
> Show that $*$ has a neutral and determine it explicitly.

I have already proven that $*$ is commutative, so it is only enough to prove that $ * $ has neutral on one side.
So we look for $e$ such that $x*e=x$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$.

Developing this we have:

$$x*e=xe+(x^2-1)(e^2-1)=x \iff x(e-1)+(x^2-1)(e-1)(e+1)=0$$
$$\iff (e-1)(x+(x^2-1)(e+1))=0\iff e-1=0 \,\, \text{ or } (x^2-1)(e+1)+x=0$$
$$\iff e=1 \, \, \text{ or } e=\dfrac{1-x-x^2}{x^2-1}$$

Then the neutral element would be 1 in case $x^2-1=0$ and $\dfrac{1-x-x^2}{x^2-1}$ in another case.

Is this correct?

Comment: The identity element should not depend on $x$ but be a *specific* element of $\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you wrote, we are looking for $e$ such that $x*e = x$ **for all** $x \in \Bbb R$.

You don't have to find $e$ in terms of $x$. You need **one** real number $e$ that works for all values of $x$.

Since the value you are looking for should work with every $x$, you should look for a value of $x$ that simplifies the finding of such $e$.

Look what happens if we choose $x=1$. Then $e$ should satisfy $1*e=1$. That is $1\cdot e+(1^2-1)(e^2-1)=1$ that reduces to $e=1$. Once you find that $e=1$ works for $x=1$, just verify that $e=1$ works for all $x$:

$x*1 = x\cdot 1 + (x^2-1)(1^2-1) = x$

Comment: Thank you, your answer perfectly complements the others.

Answer (score 7):

Other approach

If $ e $ is a neutral element, then necessarily

$$0 * e = 0$$

or

$$-(e^2-1)=0$$

So
$$e=\pm 1$$

We just need to check that $ e =1$ satisfies
$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R)\;\; e * x = x$$

Comment: Thanks for the approach

Answer (score 4):

There can be only one neutral element. And it follows from your computations that $e=1$ will work.

Comment: Thanks for the input